# Try to nAudio read the wave file wile you record it

Tags: real-time, naudio

as I wrote in the title I need to read the wave file, from an external application, while it is recording it. I noticed that until I use StopRecording () and Dispose ()
the wave file remains locked and the external application tells me the file is locked for reading

Do you have any suggestions on how I can do it?

Thank you
Mimmo

I should read the file as if it were some kind of real time

Answer (score 0):

That's really hard to do successfully. One trick I've used in the past is to create a large blank WAV file and have one process overwrite it in advance of the process that is reading.

But generally I'd recommend using something like a `BufferedWaveProvider` to supply audio for playback in a streaming scenario.